# Issues with Automatic Slideshow in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, timer, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to display 4 pictures in an automatic slideshow by building it in pure javascript. 
setInterval() and setTimeout() functions are really confusing me.

The code displays first pic and then waits for 3sec and displays the last pic and then ends.....duno why??

```
var divImages = document.getElementById("images");
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1"); //display:none using CSS
var img2 = document.getElementById("img2"); //display:none using CSS
var img3 = document.getElementById("img3"); //display:none using CSS
var img4 = document.getElementById("img4"); //display:none using CSS

window.addEventListener("load", getFirstImage);


function getFirstImage(){
  img1.style.display = "block";
}

function getSecondImage(){
  img2.style.display = "block";
  img1.style.display = "none";
}
setTimeout(getSecondImage,3000);

function getThirdImage(){
  img3.style.display = "block";
  img2.style.display = "none";
}
setTimeout(getThirdImage,3000);

function getFourthImage(){
  img4.style.display = "block";
  img3.style.display = "none";
}
setTimeout(getFourthImage,3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy but before I explain try this

```
setTimeout("alert('a')",3000)
setTimeout("alert('b')",3000)
```

You see? Both run exactly after 3 seconds why? You ask because

> setTimeouts are asynchronous

ie. **they won't wait for one another**.When javascript interpreter sees the first setTimeout it records that in it's “stuff to do after 3 secs” now after recording that it read the second setTimeout and this also gets recorded in the same list but real point to note is that almost zero time has passed between the last two events moreover due to incredible speed of js engine even if you put a huge code( even k lines of code) in between the two setTimeouts they still would run after 3 secs in order of their appearance.That's why all 4 slide functions ran after 3 secs in order of their setTimeouts since `getFourthImage()` was the last to run only its effect remained

so how do you cascade them ? Just put settimeout of a slide in it's preceding slides function sort of like alarm or like some relay race

```
window.addEventListener("load", getFirstImage);


function getFirstImage(){
  img1.style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(getSecondImage,3000);
}

function getSecondImage(){
  img2.style.display = "block";
  img1.style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(getThirdImage,3000);
}


function getThirdImage(){
  img3.style.display = "block";
  img2.style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(getFourthImage,3000);
}

function getFourthImage(){
  img4.style.display = "block";
  img3.style.display = "none";   // last one no need to put anything but you can if you wish
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was superb! Loved it!

Comment: Also wanted to ask - I am setting up clearInterval() through a Stop Button. But it only runs once the whole function or the whole 4 slides have finished running. What if I wanted the slideshow to end as soon as I clicked the button??

Comment: That's easy too .Make a global variable say `latestId` and make it hold id(return value of setTimeout) of the newest timer(becoz like a cancelled cheque , after a function scheduled by setTimeout runs there is no use of the id).It's easy just replace `setTimeout(getThirdImage,3000);` with 
`latestId = setTimeout(getThirdImage,3000);` 
now if you use `clearInterval(lastestId)` it would stop the newest timer and the function scheduled by it won't run and so will be its containing `setTimeout()` thus breaking the chain

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
setInterval(miFuncion, 2500);

var counter = 1;

function miFuncion()
 {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("foto");

    if(counter === 0 ){
      elemento.src = "http://i2.cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/141027105451-pkg-petroff-ferrari-sergio-elite-car-00014417-story-top.jpg";
    }
    else if(counter === 1){
      elemento.src = "http://www.fashiontrends.pk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Porsche-Sports-Car.jpg";
    }
    else if(counter === 2){
      elemento.src = "http://bestcarlive.com/wp-content/uploads/bmw-sports-car-wallpapers-20140720034912-53cb3c380a9cf.jpg";
    }
    else if(counter === 3){
      elemento.src = "http://media.caranddriver.com/images/17q1/674191/2018-kia-stinger-sports-sedan-photos-and-info-news-car-and-driver-photo-674389-s-450x274.jpg";
      counter = -1;
    }
    ++counter;
 }
```

```html
<img src="http://i2.cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/141027105451-pkg-petroff-ferrari-sergio-elite-car-00014417-story-top.jpg" id="foto" width="100%" height="350">
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias for this creative solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
 setInterval(function() {
 $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 1200);
</script>
```

I see that you have getElementById, so I'm assuming you have some HTML? 
this is a jquery script with assumption you have a div with a class named slideshow
any div you nest in that div will be in the slideshow! hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. unfortunately, I haven't learn jquery yet. I am forcing myself to work in javascript only. I would appreciate if you could provide a solution in pure javascript.